# How do you add aria attributes to a lightning base component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am implementing a component blueprint of the [SetupAssistant](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/setup-assistant/#Hub-with-Expandable-Steps) component which needs aria attributes to properly toggle the chevron from being open and closed.

Let's say I need to add the attribute: `aria-expanded="false"` to the actual button tag. If there is a way to access the DOM and add this, how would I do this and at what part of the rendering cycle should it be added?

The base component looks like this:

```
<lightning:buttonIcon 
      iconName="utility:switch"
      variant="bare" 
      alternativeText="toggle switch" 
      class="slds-m-right_x-small slds-m-top_x-small"/>
```

The html markup looks like this:

```
<button 
  class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-m-right_x-small slds-m-top_x-small" 
  title="Toggle details for Add Users to Your Org" 
  aria-controls="step-0-summary-action" 
  aria-expanded="false">
     <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-summary-detail__action-icon"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <use 
          xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#switch">
        </use>
    </svg>
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Toggle details for Add Users to Your Org
   </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add arbitrary values to elements outside of your own namespace, because [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html). Instead, you'd have to build your own version of the component using the [Lightning Design System](http://lightningdesignsystem.com).

Comment: Can I add them in renderer, just curious?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Not for elements out of your namespace. This is one of the things that Locker Service was designed to prevent.